# How can I use large a script to query data when using Spring Data Jpa?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have in problem statemant a script, a large script with query to database Oracle.

```sql
    SELECT /*+ LEADING(T) INDEX (T IDX_MONITORING_SIGNWORK)*/
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY t.house, t.point, t.signwork)  koltc1,
         ...
      FROM monitoring t

    ...
```

The code above is **a single query**, it is very long.

We have many similar queries.

I would not want to use that script in an annotation @Query. How can I point a path to the script. The script will be in classpath an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you create a **view** (which is a stored query, within the database) and simply reference it using a simple `select` statement, e.g.

```
create or replace view v_monitoring as
  select /*+ leading(t) index ... */
    count(*) over (...) koltc1,
    ...
  from monitoring t
  ...;
```

and then

```
select koltc1, 
       ...
from v_monitoring
where additional_conditions_if_necessary
```

Comment: We are not allowed to edit the tables and change the code in the database.